# How to resize array 20 byte to 16 byte in Java

Tags: java, arrays, aes, sha1, sha

I have this hex array of 20 Byte which the output [Digest] of SAH-1:

```
b1d5781111d84f7b3fe45a0852e59758cd7a87e5
```

How can I reuse it as 16 Byte to be the initialize IV in AES_CBC encryption algorithm as this:

```
0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00
```

The Utils class:

```
public class Utils
{
    private static String   digits = "0123456789abcdef";

    public static String toHex(byte[] data, int length)
    {
        StringBuffer    buf = new StringBuffer();

        for (int i = 0; i != length; i++)
        {
            int v = data[i] & 0xff;

            buf.append(digits.charAt(v >> 4));
            buf.append(digits.charAt(v & 0xf));
        }

        return buf.toString();
    }

    public static String toHex(byte[] data)
    {
        return toHex(data, data.length);
    }

        public static byte[] toByteArray(
        String string)
    {
        byte[]  bytes = new byte[string.length()];
        char[]  chars = string.toCharArray(); 

        for (int i = 0; i != chars.length; i++)
        {
            bytes[i] = (byte)chars[i];
        }
         return bytes;
    } }
```

Comment: _If_ you are using JCA crypto (i.e. the `javax.crypto.Cipher` class) the IV should be binary not hex (although you might send or display it in hex), and if you have a 20-byte (binary) SHA1 you don't need to resize it, you can select only the first 16 bytes (or last or middle) when you construct the `IvParameterSpec`; see the javadoc. ...

Comment: ... However, if you are hashing 'input' that is known (or provided) by an adversary, this makes your IV predictable to the adversary and predictable IVs for CBC allow attacks which may make your system insecure; that is not a programming Q and offtopic for SO but is ontopic and has numerous existing Qs on cryptography.SX and security.SX.

Answer (score 0):

**[EDIT: updated the code to use the code requested in comment]**

Use `Arrays.copyOf(keyBytes, 16)`:

```
MessageDigest hash = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1"); 
hash.update(Utils.toByteArray(input)); 
byte[] keyBytes = hash.digest();
keyBytes = Arrays.copyOf(keyBytes, 16); // use only first 128 bit
System.out.println("digest : " + Utils.toHex(keyBytes));
```

Comment: This is my code:
MessageDigest hash = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1");
hash.update(Utils.toByteArray(input));
System.out.println("digest : " + Utils.toHex(hash.digest()));

how can I mix them?

Comment: I updated my reply to use your code. Is that what you meant?

Comment: I got the same result! @Yoav Gur

Comment: That's odd. Can you share your Utils class?

Comment: I uploaded the Utils Class @Yoav Gur